# How to release memory allocated by gcnew?

Tags: memory-management, c++-cli

After some tests with help of Task Manager, I understood one thing about `gcnew` — memory allocated for local variables remaines allocated even if control leaves function, and is re-allocated only when control re-enters this function — so I'm in perplexity, how to deallocate memory myself. Here is some example of the problem:

```
void Foo(void)
{
    System::Text::StringBuilder ^ t = gcnew System::Text::StringBuilder("");
    int i = 0;
    while(++i < 20000000) t->Append(i);
    return;
}
```

As I mentioned, memory for variable `t` remains after leaving `Foo()`, `delete` not work as it works for `new`, and calling `Foo()` once, only gives me pointless allocated memory.

Comment: Why did you allocate it dynamically in the first place?

Comment: why the hell did you used managed C++ in the first place? it's like eating a cake with no sugar.

Comment: The memory allocated to a process with a garbage collection system is only limited by its performance and good citizen goals. You should expect that it won't unnecessarily fill up your hard drive.

Comment: @TomBlodget, but I don't need this memory, as this function will be never called

Comment: @DavidHaim C++/CLI is primarily meant for interop between C++ and .NET, try to do that with vanilla C++ - that's like eating a cake with salt ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski it's called PInvoke.

Comment: @DavidHaim P/Invoke only allows you to call C functions (or `extern "C"`). I'd rather say it's called COM interop if you want anything object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

This is `gcnew`, which means garbage collected allocation. It will be disposed and deallocated by GC thread

Answer (score 0):

Your function uses memory for code and data. The code is a fixed amount and will be used the entire time the library or program is loaded. The data is only used when the function is executing.

Data used by a program is either static or dynamic. Static data is laid out by the compiler and is basically equivalent to code (except that it might be marked as non-executable and/or read-only to prevent accidents). Dynamic data is temporary and allocated from a stack or heap (or CPU registers).

In a classic program, the stack and heap share the same memory address range with the stack at one end, growing toward the heap and the heap at the other end, trying not to grow into the stack. However, with modern address ranges on the order of 1TB, a heap generally has a lot of room.

Keep in mind that when a program requests an address range, it's just signaling to the operating system that it's okay to use that address for data reading, data writing and/or code execution. Until it actually puts something there, there is no load on the system. Also keep in mind with a virtual memory system, process memory is effectively allocated on the swap file/device (hard drive) with optimizations especially using RAM for caching, copy on write and many other techniques. (Data written to a memory address might never make it to the swap file, but that's up to the operating system.)

---

The data your function needs is for the two variables: `t` and `i`. `t` is a reference to a garbage collected object. `i` is an integer. Both are quite small and short-lived. You could think of them as being on the stack. When the function returns, the stack frame is popped and their memory is reused by the next stack operation. If you are looking at memory allocation, there won't be a change because the amount of memory allocated to the stack would not be changed.

Now in the execution of your function, a new object is created and, the way it's filled with data, it takes up quite a bit of memory. You could consider that object to be created in the heap. You don't need to delete it since it is a garbage collection object. When the garbage collector runs by walking all objects reachable from a set of root objects, it will find that the object is not reachable and add its space to a free list. When space for a new object is needed that doesn't fit into any blocks on the free list, more of the heap's address range will be used.

The CLR heap is compactable, which means it can move objects around in order to coalesce free blocks. Using this ability, it can move objects out of areas of allocated memory and give it back to the operating system, thereby freeing up space in the swap file.

So, there are three things that have to happen for you to see a reduction in the amount of memory allocated to the process:

1. The garbage collection has run to find unreachable objects.
2. The heap has been compacted.
3. The heap allocation has been reduced.

None of these things are really necessary until the swap file can't grow anymore. Obviously, the system has been designed for performance and to be a good citizen so it wouldn't take it that far. You can influence when garbage collection runs but this is only very rarely helpful and is generally not done.